# MySQL count and case with one to many relationship

Tags: mysql

My first question here.

I got 2 tables with one to many relationship:

1. policies

| id | issue_date | user_id | insurance_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-2-2021 | 100 | apartment |
| 2 | 1-2-2021 | 200 | car |

2. policy_details

| id | policy_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | type A |
| 1 | 1 | type A |
| 2 | 1 | type B |
| 3 | 1 | type C |

1 policy record can have many policy_details records.

I need to count the policies rows with some case,
and I need to join the policy_details as well because I count them also.

Example to simple query:

```
SELECT
user_id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN `insurance_type` = 'apartment' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as totalApartmentType,
COUNT(CASE WHEN policy_details.type = 'typeA' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as totalTypeA
FROM `policies`
JOIN `policy_details` ON policy_details.policy_id = policies.id
AND MONTH(`issue_date`) = 2
GROUP BY (`user_id`)
```

The problem here is that if 1 policy connected to 2 policy_details records for example,
the count will be 2 and it should be 1, cause I need to count the policy record, not the policy_details joined records.
And if policy_details has 5 records connected to policy, the count will be 5. (should be 1).

The result I need for the query above:

| user_id | totalApartmentType | totalTypeA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 2 |

Can it be done guys?

Comment: Why do you need to join `policy_details` -- which fields from it you want to use? Can you provide the schema (as text, not as image please), so we can see which table has which column? For instance, where is `insurance_type`, and where is `issue_date`?

Comment: @trincot
Hey thank you for the answer. I edited the question and added tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` making sure you generate the `id` instead of 1 in case the condition is fulfilled:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN insurance_type = 'apartment' 
                    THEN policies.id 
                    ELSE NULL 
               END) AS totalApartmentType,
```